# jQuery localScroll - how to add class to clicked <a>?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I got a scrolling content controlled via href's in navigation. I use localScroll to scroll the content. So question is how to add class to  attribute of currently displayedpart of a content. That's how I initiate scroll

```
<script style="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.navigation').localScroll();
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks,
Arek

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
<script style="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.navigation').localScroll();
            $('.navigation').find('a').click(selectNav);
            function selectNav() {
              $(this)
                .parents('ul:first') 
                  .find('a') 
                    .removeClass('selected') 
                  .end() 
                .end()
                .addClass('selected');
                }
                function trigger(data) {
                  var el = $('.navigation').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);
                  selectNav.call(el);
                    }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for that `<a>` do you have any id or you want to add class on click of every

if it is something like this `<a id="target" >` you can try the below

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  $("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
});
```

Comment: no, there's no id. But i figured it out. check out answer below

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this too, and the answer by @arekk gave me an idea.  I implemented mine this way

```
$('#sub-menu a').click(function(){
    var links = $('#sub-menu a');
    links.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I hope this works for anybody looking