# localscroll active link url recognition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Via localscroll and scrollto i built a horizontal sliding page ([Environment](http://mhdev.square7.ch/ngoctest)) also adds hashes to the url. example: when clicking a link in the nav from localScroll it adds the hash in the url (index.html#media).

Now via Localscroll there is no active link support and i wanted to add that and found some solutions here: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181836/jquery-localscroll-how-to-add-class-to-clicked-a)

i was happy but then i tried to reload the page and when the user is, for example in the media section, there is no support for recognition of the url and it doesnt add the selected class to the nav link that is currently selected in the url.

so i did more research and found that site: [Website](http://intelligentstudios.co.uk/HTML/index-sixlinks.html)

great but it didnt work for my horizontal setup.
i barely started my knowledge about javascript and i even don't know how to jquery at all so i modified the script with my logic and went so far:

i adds the class, even when i scroll via the mousewheel it nicely add the class to all nav links. BUT: it doesn't remove them.

```
<script style="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var sections = {},
            _width   = $(window).width(),
            i        = 0;

        // Grab positions of our sections 
        $('.section').each(function(){
            sections[this.name] = $(this).offset().left;
        });

        $(document).scroll(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                pos   = $this.scrollLeft();

            for(i in sections){
                if(sections[i] > pos && sections[i] < pos + _width){
                    $('#nav ul li a').removeClass('selected');
                    $('#nav_' + i).addClass('selected');
                }  
            }
        });
    });

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];
        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.left;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft:target_top}, 800);
    });
</script>
```

How to update the links so it removes the selected class?

Edit: i think i'm close
i think it needs changes in the for header

```
if(sections[i] > pos && sections[i] < pos + _width)
```

What are the needed changes to assign the class "selected" to the current viewed slide